# Best way to structure conversion method

Tags: java

How can I best structure the following code, to make it read the best.

I have a method that take a Message and then converts to a MyMessage object.

```
public MyMessage convertToMyMessage(Message message){
    MyMessage myMessage = new MyMessage();
    myMessage.setId(message.getId() + "1");
    ...
    ...
    etc
    if(message instanceOf TheMessage){
        myMessage.setNode((TheMessage)message).getNode2());
        ...
        ...
        etc - converting from TheMessage to MyMessge
    }
}
```

The part that I don't like is that specifics for **TheMessage**.  How can this be refactored to make it more readable, since this method is long.

In the case I am thinking of, I will not have many message types only **Message** and **TheMessage**, so I think refactoring to a pattern maybe to extreme.

One refactor I had considered is to *extract method*.

```
public MyMessage convertToMyMessage(Message message){
    MyMessage myMessage = new MyMessage();
    myMessage.setId(message.getId() + "1");
    ...
    ...
    etc
    convertTheMessageToMyMessage(myMessage, message);
}

private void convertTheMessageToMyMessage(MyMessage myMessage, Message message){
    if(message instanceOf TheMessage){
        myMessage.setNode((TheMessage)message).getNode2());
        ...
        ...
        etc - converting from TheMessage to MyMessge
    }
}
```

This is not great since we changing an object outside the scope of the method.

What options would I have to make this method more readable.

Comment: you could change the method signature to receive both messages the source and the target, this way is clear that the target object is build outside of the method. something like this `private void convertTheMessageToMyMessage(Message sourceMessage, Message targetMessage)` where targetMessage should be `myMessage` instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest externalizing it into an interface:

```
public interface MessageConverter<S, T> {
    T convert(S source); 
}
```

If you're really smart you might consider using the Java JDK [8 functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/package-summary.html).  Lambdas are open to you that way.  The interface I suggested is nothing more than the `Function<T, R>` by another name.  That one can be composed - very useful.

Comment: How would this work, as I want to convert to MyMessage using the default mappings from the Message class but if it happens to be a TheMessage instance, it should also copy these.  I will update the example.

Comment: Polymorphism eliminates instanceof code.  You'll have one implementation that will convert to MyMessage (bad naming) using default mappings, and another one that takes TheMessage (more bad naming) and converts it appropriately.  Dynamic typing will choose the right implementation.